# Data attribute becomes integer

Tags: jquery

Check out this simple example [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZxUU/2/)

```
<div id ="a" data-siteid="00005">00005 turns into:</div>
<div id="b" data-siteid="S00005">S00005 turns into: </div>
```

code

```
$('#a').append($('#a').data("siteid"));
$('#b').append($('#b').data("siteid"));
```

​
result

```
00005 turns into:5
S00005 turns into: S00005
```

I would like to return "00005" and "S00005".

Comment: Sorry @FelixKling, it's a string, but not the string I needed. My siteid is actual the string '00005'

Comment: Yeah... I understood your question, deleted my comment. A bit more explanation would have helper though ;) For example, that `S00005` is used to *force* returning a string and that this should show that `00005` is converted to a number.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try

```
$('#a').append($('#a').attr('data-siteid'));
$('#b').append($('#b').attr('data-siteid'));
```

[**From the jQuery Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for also providing the doc!

Comment: The docs clearly say that `attr()` returns a `string` but simple code like `element.attr('data-text', '12'); text = element.attr('data-text');` returns a number for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string
>   without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

From here: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: I think @binarious was faster :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

JQuery returns integer if you have a value as a string, i.e. "one integer value", i.e. "100", if it is not, i.e. "0, 3" then it returns it as string. Beware, JQuery's data() function doesn't always return what you expect, check the type and process it.I hope this helps too.

```
if (typeof( $("xyz").data() ) == 'number') { 
   do Something 
} 
else { 
   do Something else 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this is a slightly older post, but another way you can approach this is to convert the data attribute value to a string:

```
$('#a').data("siteid").toString()
```

or

```
$('#a').data().siteid.toString()
```

Some examples of how this can work:

```
> (12345).toString()
"12345"

> (14.5).toString()
"14.5"

> (-14.5).toString()
"-14.5"

> "bob".toString()
"bob"

> (true).toString()
"true"

> ({a: "b"}).toString()
"[object Object]"

>(function(){console.log("bob")}).toString()
"function (){console.log("bob")}"
```

The parenthesis in the example are there to avoid assigning variables, since you cannot directly use `#toString` on the number directly: `123.toString()`, but you can when it assigned to a variable or enclosed in parenthesis: `(123).toString()`.

Just remember that you won't be able to convert null or undefined to a string.

Also something interesting happens with arrays and undefined and null values:

```
> (["bob", 123, true, null, undefined, this]).toString()
"bob,123,true,,,[object Window]"
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem: in OP case the data was `00005`. When reading from data it'll become 5 (because of the implicit conversion) and then the toString will make it "5".

Comment: Nooooo.  Converting to a string may be too late.  For example, if the number is 64-bits long, it would have been converted to a float point, losing some resolution.  Subsequent conversion back to integer would be wrong, wrong!