# Splice JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, splice

Here's my attempt at trying to remove a value from an array dynamically

```
$('.btn-remove').click(function() {
    var players = ["compare","13076","13075","13077","12755"];
    var removePlayer = $(this).data('player');
    var idx = $.inArray(removePlayer, players);
    if (idx != -1) {
        players.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    window.location = "/" + players.join('/');
})
```

For example, `$(this).data('player')` could equal **13077** and i'd want it to remove that value from the array and then redirect to the url which is attached to the `window.location` variable

Comment: So you want to redirect to `compare/13076/13075/12755`?

Comment: In this specific instance that I've quoted, that'd be correct @RayToal

Comment: Just a guess, but probably a duplicate of [Issue with jQuery data() treating string as number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296985/data-attribute-becomes-integer) or similar -- the data value from `$(this).data('player')` is auto-converted to a number, so the `$.inArray` test fails comparing a number against a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) converts the `player` data string value to a number:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's representation... **The string value "100" is converted to the number 100.**

In your example, you're doing

```
$.inArray(13077, ["compare","13076","13075","13077","12755"]);
```

rather than

```
$.inArray("13077", ["compare","13076","13075","13077","12755"]);
```

You must either convert the data value back to a string (e.g., `removePlayer += ""`) or fill the array with number values instead of strings.